# Response from Subscribe of async get request to be used in another get request

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I know this question has been asked a number of times but still none of the answer solves my problem. I have a service which fetch a URL from a json file.

```
@Injectable()
export class HostConfigService {  
getHostUrl()
{
  return this.http.get("File path").map((response : Response) => 
  response.json()); // this returns a URL ex: http://localhost:8080
}
}
```

I want to use response from above URL to construct URL's in multiple files for rest calls from the angular application.

```
export class GetData{
constructor(private hostConfigService: HostConfigService, private _http: 
Http) { }
getData(){
    this.hostConfigService.getHostUrl().subscribe((res) => this.hostUrl = 
    res.hostUrl); //this.hostUrl should return undefined outside subscribe 
    block
    this.restUrl = this.hostUrl + "/getData";
    return this._http.get(this.restUrl).map((response : 
    Response) => response.json());
  }
}
```

Response from getData function is also read from a subscribe. I already have used subscribe inside subscribe but that gives me error Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'. Can you please help me with a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use `environments` for the host url?

Comment: where you have defined this.hostUrl?

Comment: I agree, `environment` would be much better, and is meant to handle this kind of issue

Comment: `getData() : any {}` try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use environment, but if you don't want to, the correct way of using your functions is like this

```js
export class GetData {

constructor(private hostConfigService: HostConfigService, private _http: Http) { }

  getData() {
    this.hostConfigService.getHostUrl()
    .flatMap(url => this._http.get(url).map((response : Response) => response.json()));
  }
}
```

What happens is that you make the first call, and once the result is there, you make the second.

Answer (score 1):

As you are already getting the host url from a static file it would be much better to use the `environments`

In the `environments/environment.ts` file you can define the url as such:

```
export const environment = {
    ...
    hostUrl: 'www.thisismyhosturl.com',
    ...
};
```

Next you can use this variable in your service

```
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

export class GetData{
constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getData(){
        this.restUrl = environment.hostUrl + "/getData";
        return this._http.get(this.restUrl).map((response : 
        Response) => response.json());
    }
}
```

Using this approach removes the need for your `hostConfigService`

Comment: @trichetriche, since it is async call by using flatmap it slows the response on UI which means when i subscribe the response and displays on UI it shows blank for sometime and populates response after 30 seconds and when i hardcode the URL it shows the response in less than a second. Can you please suggest me some other way in which i can get a fast response?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @trichetriche , using flatmap solved my problem. Guys i cant use environment.ts to store the host URL since the host URL will be different for every user and for that reason i need to store them into a static file in assets folder

Comment: Another option could be to drop the Url into local storage.